# Difference in C# BST timezone period (Windows vs Linux) in 1971

Tags: c#, .net, linux, timezone, .net-core

My system is set to London (GMT) time with regional settings set to UK defaults.

When running on Ubuntu 16.04, .NET Core 1.1, this code produces the following:

```
DateTime.Now: 27/01/2017 11:03:31
DateTime.UtcNow: 27/01/2017 11:03:31

new DateTime(1968, 02, 18).ToUniversalTime(): 18/02/1968 00:00:00
new DateTime(1968, 02, 19).ToUniversalTime(): 18/02/1968 23:00:00

new DateTime(1971, 10, 31).ToUniversalTime(): 30/10/1971 23:00:00
new DateTime(1971, 11, 01).ToUniversalTime(): 01/11/1971 00:00:00
```

These expressions when ran on Windows Server 2008 R2, .NET Core 1.1 (and also .NET Framework 4.5.1), produce:

```
DateTime.Now: 27/01/2017 10:55:47
DateTime.UtcNow: 27/01/2017 10:55:47

new DateTime(1968, 02, 18).ToUniversalTime(): 18/02/1968 00:00:00
new DateTime(1968, 02, 19).ToUniversalTime(): 19/02/1968 00:00:00

new DateTime(1971, 10, 31).ToUniversalTime(): 30/10/1971 23:00:00
new DateTime(1971, 11, 01).ToUniversalTime(): 01/11/1971 00:00:00
```

The change to BST seems to occur in 1971 (rather than 1968 like Linux) - on a seemingly arbitrary date.

```
new DateTime(1971, 03, 28).ToUniversalTime(): 28/03/1971 00:00:00
new DateTime(1971, 03, 29).ToUniversalTime(): 28/03/1971 23:00:00
```

Linux seems to be correct in the actual conversions here based on what happened with BST during 1968 and 1971 (the implementation of [British Standard Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Summer_Time#Periods_of_deviation)), whilst Windows seems to not account for this and introduces a different period.

What's the reason for this behaviour?

Comment: Bug in .NET Core or in Windows BST tables, it seems. Doesn't NodaTime ship its own tables now because of issues with Microsoft-provided ones for historical data? http://nodatime.org/tzdb/latest.txt

Comment: I've just ran into the same issue with Oct 28th in 1995. Windows considers the date in BST and Linux is aware that it wasn't. I guess this is never going to get fixed given this question was asked 6 years ago.